# How to comment/remove all print statements from Python codebase?

Tags: python, regex, django, logging, comments

I have this regex to remove all print statements from a python codebase:

```
for f in $(find . -name '*.py') ;
do
egrep -v '^[ \t]print ' $f > $f.new
mv $f.new $f
done
```

but it doesn't really work..

```
find . -name '*.py' | xargs egrep '^[ \t]*print'
```

Still prints out the print statements from my code.. :(

However, I want to modify this to *comment* out all the lines that have print statements in them(so they arent completely gone from the codebase).

How can I efficiently do this? better still is there an automated way to convert everything to logging framework?

Comment: `[ \t]` matches *exactly one* whitespace. You want `[ \t]*`.

Comment: Python 2.x or Python 3?

Comment: 2.x currently. i considered using the 2to3 tool --fix=print but that just converts it into a print fuction and causes a bunch of errors in the codebase also..

Comment: [ \t] is the same as \s on most machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sed is the tool for the job.

```
find . -name '*.py' -exec sed -ri "s/(^\s*)(print.*$)/#\1\2/g" {} \;
```

For Mac OS X or BSD:

```
find . -name '*.py' -exec sed -Ei "s/\(^[[:space:]]*\)\(print.*$\)/#\1\2/g" {} \;
```

Comment: give me an error :: sed: illegal option -- r
if i remove -r it give me error : sed: 1: "./scripts/update_hosts.py": invalid command code .

Comment: ah, replace the `r` with `E` in your case.

Comment: if i want to remove print statements instead of comment out?

Comment: @NaveenAgarwal ```find . -name '*.py' -exec sed -ri "s/(^\s*)(print.*$)//g" {} \;```